# Stop tailing log

Tags: logs, console, tail, job-control, installer-anaconda

I have a problem, I accidentally did tail -f on a log, but now I cant quit! - Its the anaconda log during a redhat install. Control-C doesn't seem to work, I guess due to it saying sh: no job control in this shell ? But I really need to stop tailing as the install is one, and I have to reboot the box.

Comment: Try typing Control-\ (that is, the backslash key), which will usually generate a SIGQUIT and terminate the foreground process.

Comment: Didnt work :( Its whatever shell (busybox?) rhel says during installl, via some retro HP lights out cards virtual serial port.

Answer (score 1):

Log in on a different terminal/shell.
Use `ps` to check the PID.
Use `kill` to stop the process.

Comment: I cant, I have one serial console.

Comment: Ouch... And no second serial terminal available I presume? Is it a remote system?

Comment: If it is a local system then you could also try to connect a screen and keyboard to it.. But if that was the case you would have probably already thought of it.

Comment: Remote system. I just had to power cycle it.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. But maybe next time you ask a question maybe it would be good to tell the whole story to avoid more or less useless answers... like mine... ;-)